# No muestra el Throw New Error en Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con esta funcion:

```
function Validate_Number(jsonFile){
  jsonFile.forEach(f =>{
    f.Notification.forEach(e =>{
      e.Means.forEach(function(v){
        let data = Object.keys(v);
        data.forEach(function( x ){
          if(properties2.indexOf( x ) > -1){
            if(v.Number != undefined && v.Code != undefined && Number.isInteger(v.Number) === true && Number.isInteger(v.Code) === true){
                for(var etiqueta in e.Contents){
                  if(etiqueta === "Message"){

                    }else{
                      throw new Error("Error code: E0008 \nValidation code: V0008 \nDescription: Code tag is not a number")
                    }
                }
              }
            }
        })
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Y cuando entra al "else" no muestra el mensaje de error solo se detiene. ¿Alguien sabe porque podria ser?

Answer (score 0):

prueba con lo siguiente:

```
function Validate_Number(jsonFile){
    try
    {
      jsonFile.forEach(f =>{
        f.Notification.forEach(e =>{
          e.Means.forEach(function(v){
            let data = Object.keys(v);
            data.forEach(function( x ){
              if(properties2.indexOf( x ) > -1){
                if(v.Number != undefined && v.Code != undefined && Number.isInteger(v.Number) === true && Number.isInteger(v.Code) === true){
                    for(var etiqueta in e.Contents){
                      if(etiqueta === "Message"){

                        }else{
                          throw new Error("Error code: E0008 \nValidation code: V0008 \nDescription: Code tag is not a number")
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
            })
            })
          })
        })
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        // Implementa la funcionalidad de un error
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```